# Cordova SQLite save BLOB

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, blob, ionic-framework

I have a problem with Cordova SQLite plugin.

How can I save BLOB image to SQLite?

I have BLOB object in JS:

```
Blob:{
size: 96874
type: "image/jpeg"
__proto__: Blob
length: 1}
```

And I trying to save it

```
INSERT INTO images (img) VALUES (?);
```

And when i trying to get this image:

```
SELECT img FROM images
```

I get this string:

```
img: "{"type":"image\/jpeg","size":96874}"
```

How can i convert it to BLOB again?

Also i trying to save images in base64, but i can't save big images to SQLite, because base64 string is very huge. (It's works with small images)

Please, help me and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot save JavaScript Blob objects to the SQLite Plugin. It doesn't support the Blob format. Yes I know it has a `BLOB` type, but confusingly it's not the same thing. :)

WebSQL/SQLite Plugin does support binary strings as an alternative to Blobs. However, you may run into issues because there are numerous bugs in the implementation on both iOS and Android ([some details are here](http://pouchdb.com/2014/09/22/3.0.6.html)).

In PouchDB we worked around these issues, so the attachment API abstracts everything away for you. Follow the [PouchDB attachment guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html) and it will convert Blobs for you and store them in the database. To create a PouchDB that talks to the SQLite Plugin, you will need to do the following:

```
/* prefer websql, which will actually use the SQLite Plugin if available */
var db = new PouchDB('mydbname', {adapter: 'websql'});
if (!db.adapter) {
  /* fall back to IndexedDB for FirefoxOS, Windows Phone, etc. */
  db = new PouchDB('mydbname');
}
```

If you want to convert between Blobs and binary strings or a variety of other formats, check out [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util).

Comment: For some reason WWAHost fails the check for IndexedDB :-/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [blob literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) and the [hex](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) function to treat blob values as hex strings at the interface between SQL and JavaScript, that works fine.

Comment: Could you explain? When i get javascript BLOB object what shall i do with him? Sorry for stupid questions, but i'm little confused with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

how big are your images? I've build an app which saved images to app database, see this [inventory-service](https://github.com/holisticon/flynn-book-scanner/blob/master/app/src/scripts/modules/srv.inventory.js#L136). I've using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com) and a customer [base64-service](https://github.com/holisticon/flynn-book-scanner/blob/master/app/src/scripts/modules/srv.base64.js).
You can also find the App in the [official stores](http://holisticon.github.io/flynn-book-scanner/).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to simply store your pictures as flat files, with unique file names of course, and store the *references* in your sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save binary image to local sqlite but one solution exists if you use camera or gallery to upload image:

```
photoOption(src, val) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 60,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: src,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      let FILE_URI = imageData; // this is FILE_URI (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myproject/cache/1022001.jpg) like this
      this.insertImgIntoSqlite(FILE_URI);
    }, (err) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
```

You can save `FILE_URI` in local sqlite and when you want to upload to server convert to `BINARY_FILE` and upload to server