# can we store a video in sqlite database using ionic framework? if it does how can we store it?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 for developing the mobile App and using sqlite plugin (I want only sqlite rather than pouchDB) for database to store video. But I didn't find any docs regarding the video storing into sqlite-storage. Please let me know if we can store a video into sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

Someone did ask something similar.

[Cordova SQLite save BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623616/cordova-sqlite-save-blob)

Though this answer suggests it's not possible, the docs on Cordova-sqlite-storage-plugin suggest it is in their [docs](http://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

> SELECT BLOB column value type is not supported consistently across all
>   platforms (not supported on Windows). It is recommended to use the
>   built-in HEX function to SELECT BLOB column data in hexadecimal
>   format, working consistently across all platforms. As an alternative:
>   SELECT BLOB in Base64 format is supported by litehelpers /
>   cordova-sqlite-ext (permissive license terms) and litehelpers /
>   Cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free (GPL or commercial license
>   options).

Check this [plugin](http://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util) for converting to BLOB in case possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Danel Ceresa